# Allow element to go beyond a table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm having a problem building tooltips for elements inside an html table. Basically I have this:

```
Table1
a    b
c    d
Table2
a    b
c    d
```

Every element (a,b,c,d) is composed of an image and an empty paragraph which will host the description. Every image has a function, `onMouseOver=showDescription(idParagraphToBeShowed, Text)`, which shows the description of the image when you hover the mouse. The `<td>` elements have the CSS attribute:

```
position: relative
```

and the paragraphs have:

```
position: absolute
text-align: center
z-index: 1
```

In this way I'm able to center the description with respect to the image on each cell of the table.

All works perfectly, the only (big) problem is that is I hover (for example) on the cell c, Table1 the description follows on the cell b instead of going beyond the table covering Table2 and its cells. This is of course an extremely nasty bug.

So, how can I 'allow' the description to go over other elements outside its container?

Comment: Any chance you could set up a fiddle for this? I think I know what's wrong, but I need to confirm it.

Comment: excuse me, what does setting up a fiddle mean?

Comment: I provide you a link to the page itself http://luigitiburzi.com/books/

Comment: That is impressive, not sure how you even accomplished that. I'll have an answer for you shortly.

Comment: I'm surprised too and I don't know how and why it happened...